# Installation problems with Playframework 2.1.0 on Windows 7

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

Im trying to run a fresh copy of Play framework 2.1.0. I've set the environment variable and all the requirements are met but I get the following console error when I type in "play help" in the console:

```
    setting 'ivy.default.settings.dir' to 'jar:file:/F:/Play/framework/sbt/sbt-launch.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings'
setting 'ivy.basedir' to 'C:\Users\user M\.'
setting 'ivy.default.conf.dir' to 'jar:file:/F:/Play/framework/sbt/sbt-launch.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings'
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.SshResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.VsftpResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.version.PatternVersionMatcher in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.trigger.LogTrigger in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.ant.AntBuildTrigger in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.IvyRepResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.signer.bouncycastle.OpenPGPSignatureGenerator in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.conflict.RegexpConflictManager in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.SFTPResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.osgi.updatesite.UpdateSiteResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.ant.AntCallTrigger in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.MirroredURLResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.packager.PackagerResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.DualResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.VfsResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.JarResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.osgi.obr.OBRResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define glob matcher: org.apache.ivy.plugins.matcher.GlobPatternMatcher was not found.
setting 'sbt.ivy.home' to 'F:\Play\framework\..\repository'
setting 'java.runtime.name' to 'Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment'
setting 'sun.boot.library.path' to 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin'
setting 'java.vm.version' to '21.0-b17'
setting 'user.country.format' to 'BG'
setting 'java.vm.vendor' to 'Oracle Corporation'
setting 'java.vendor.url' to 'http://java.oracle.com/'
setting 'path.separator' to ';'
setting 'java.vm.name' to 'Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM'
setting 'file.encoding.pkg' to 'sun.io'
setting 'user.country' to 'US'
setting 'user.script' to ''
setting 'sun.java.launcher' to 'SUN_STANDARD'
setting 'sun.os.patch.level' to 'Service Pack 1'
setting 'java.vm.specification.name' to 'Java Virtual Machine Specification'
setting 'user.dir' to 'C:\Users\user M'
setting 'java.runtime.version' to '1.7.0-b147'
setting 'sbt.boot.properties' to 'file:///F:/Play/framework/sbt/sbt.boot.properties'
setting 'java.awt.graphicsenv' to 'sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment'
setting 'java.endorsed.dirs' to 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\endorsed'
setting 'os.arch' to 'amd64'
setting 'java.io.tmpdir' to 'C:\Users\ALEXAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\'
setting 'line.separator' to '
'
setting 'java.vm.specification.vendor' to 'Oracle Corporation'
setting 'user.variant' to ''
setting 'os.name' to 'Windows 7'
setting 'sun.jnu.encoding' to 'Cp1251'
setting 'java.library.path' to 'C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8;C:\wamp\www\yii\framework;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;F:\Play;.'
setting 'java.specification.name' to 'Java Platform API Specification'
setting 'java.class.version' to '51.0'
setting 'play.home' to 'F:\Play\framework\.'
setting 'sun.management.compiler' to 'HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers'
setting 'os.version' to '6.1'
setting 'user.home' to 'C:\Users\user M'
setting 'user.timezone' to 'Europe/Helsinki'
setting 'java.awt.printerjob' to 'sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob'
setting 'file.encoding' to 'UTF-8'
setting 'java.specification.version' to '1.7'
setting 'java.class.path' to 'F:\Play\framework\sbt\sbt-launch.jar'
setting 'user.name' to 'user M'
setting 'play.version' to '2.1.0'
setting 'java.vm.specification.version' to '1.7'
setting 'sun.java.command' to 'F:\Play\framework\sbt\sbt-launch.jar help'
setting 'java.home' to 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre7'
setting 'sun.arch.data.model' to '64'
setting 'user.language' to 'en'
setting 'java.specification.vendor' to 'Oracle Corporation'
setting 'user.language.format' to 'bg'
setting 'awt.toolkit' to 'sun.awt.windows.WToolkit'
setting 'java.vm.info' to 'mixed mode'
setting 'java.version' to '1.7.0'
setting 'java.ext.dirs' to 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext'
setting 'sun.boot.class.path' to 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\classes'
setting 'java.vendor' to 'Oracle Corporation'
setting 'file.separator' to '\'
setting 'java.vendor.url.bug' to 'http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/'
setting 'sun.io.unicode.encoding' to 'UnicodeLittle'
setting 'sun.cpu.endian' to 'little'
setting 'sun.desktop' to 'windows'
setting 'sun.cpu.isalist' to 'amd64'
setting 'ivy.default.ivy.user.dir' to 'F:\Play\framework\.\..\repository'
setting 'ivy.home' to 'F:\Play\framework\.\..\repository'
setting 'ivy.cache.dir' to 'F:\Play\framework\.\..\repository\cache'
no default cache defined: set to F:\Play\framework\.\..\repository\cache
setting 'ivy.checksums' to 'sha1,md5'
setting 'ivy.basedir' to 'F:\Play\framework\.\sbt\boot'
setting 'basedir' to 'F:\Play\framework\.\sbt\boot'
setting 'scala' to '2.9.2'
:: resolving dependencies :: org.scala-sbt#boot-app;1.0
    confs: [default]
    validate = true
    refresh = false
resolving dependencies for configuration 'default'
== resolving dependencies for org.scala-sbt#boot-app;1.0 [default]
loadData of org.scala-sbt#boot-app;1.0 of rootConf=default
== resolving dependencies org.scala-sbt#boot-app;1.0->org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}} [default->default(compile)]
loadData of org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}} of rootConf=default
    using redefined-public to resolve org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}
redefined-public: Checking cache for: dependency: org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}} {default=[default(compile)]}
redefined-public: no namespace defined: using system
    no ivy file in cache for org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}: tried F:\Play\framework\.\..\repository\cache\org.scala-sbt\sbt\ivy-${{sbt.version}}.xml
redefined-public: no latest strategy defined: using default
local: no namespace defined: using system
    no ivy file in cache for org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}: tried F:\Play\framework\.\..\repository\cache\org.scala-sbt\sbt\ivy-${{sbt.version}}.xml
     trying F:\Play\repository\local\org.scala-sbt\sbt\${{sbt.version}}\ivys\ivy.xml
        tried F:\Play\repository\local\org.scala-sbt\sbt\${{sbt.version}}\ivys\ivy.xml
    local: resource not reachable for org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}: res=F:\Play\repository\local\org.scala-sbt\sbt\${{sbt.version}}\ivys\ivy.xml
    local: no ivy file found for org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}
Maven2 Local: no namespace defined: using system
    no ivy file in cache for org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}: tried F:\Play\framework\.\..\repository\cache\org.scala-sbt\sbt\ivy-${{sbt.version}}.xml
     trying file://C:\Users\user M/.m2/repository/org/scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/sbt-${{sbt.version}}.pom
        tried file://C:\Users\user M/.m2/repository/org/scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/sbt-${{sbt.version}}.pom
    Maven2 Local: resource not reachable for org/scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}: res=file://C:/Users/user M/.m2/repository/org/scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/sbt-${{sbt.version}}.pom
    Maven2 Local: no ivy file found for org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}
typesafe-ivy-releases: no namespace defined: using system
    no ivy file in cache for org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}: tried F:\Play\framework\.\..\repository\cache\org.scala-sbt\sbt\ivy-${{sbt.version}}.xml
     trying http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/ivys/ivy.xml
        tried http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/ivys/ivy.xml
HTTP response status: 404 url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/$%7B%7Bsbt.version%7D%7D/ivys/ivy.xml
CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/$%7B%7Bsbt.version%7D%7D/ivys/ivy.xml
    typesafe-ivy-releases: resource not reachable for org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}: res=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/ivys/ivy.xml
    typesafe-ivy-releases: no ivy file found for org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}
Maven Central: no namespace defined: using system
    no ivy file in cache for org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}: tried F:\Play\framework\.\..\repository\cache\org.scala-sbt\sbt\ivy-${{sbt.version}}.xml
     trying http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/sbt-${{sbt.version}}.pom
        tried http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/sbt-${{sbt.version}}.pom
HTTP response status: 404 url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/$%7B%7Bsbt.version%7D%7D/sbt-$%7B%7Bsbt.version%7D%7D.pom
CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/$%7B%7Bsbt.version%7D%7D/sbt-$%7B%7Bsbt.version%7D%7D.pom
    Maven Central: resource not reachable for org/scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}: res=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/sbt-${{sbt.version}}.pom
    Maven Central: no ivy file found for org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}
WARN:   module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}
WARN: ==== local: tried
WARN:   F:\Play\repository\local\org.scala-sbt\sbt\${{sbt.version}}\ivys\ivy.xml
WARN: ==== Maven2 Local: tried
WARN:   file://C:\Users\user M/.m2/repository/org/scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/sbt-${{sbt.version}}.pom
WARN: ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
WARN:   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/ivys/ivy.xml
WARN: ==== Maven Central: tried
WARN:   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/sbt-${{sbt.version}}.pom
Nbr of module to sort : 0
    resolved ivy file produced in F:\Play\framework\.\..\repository\cache\resolved-org.scala-sbt-boot-app-1.0.xml
:: downloading artifacts ::
:: resolution report :: resolve 2500ms :: artifacts dl 0ms
WARN:   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
WARN:   ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
WARN:   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
WARN:   :: org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}: not found
WARN:   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

Nbr of module to sort : 0
    report for org.scala-sbt#boot-app;1.0 default produced in F:\Play\framework\.\..\repository\cache\org.scala-sbt-boot-app-default.xml
    resolve done (2500ms resolve - 0ms download)

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}

    ==== local: tried

      F:\Play\repository\local\org.scala-sbt\sbt\${{sbt.version}}\ivys\ivy.xml

    ==== Maven2 Local: tried

      file://C:\Users\user M/.m2/repository/org/scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/sbt-${{sbt.version}}.pom

    ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

      http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/ivys/ivy.xml

    ==== Maven Central: tried

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/${{sbt.version}}/sbt-${{sbt.version}}.pom

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.scala-sbt#sbt;${{sbt.version}}: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
java.lang.RuntimeException: not found
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.IvyNode.loadData(IvyNode.java:238)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.VisitNode.loadData(VisitNode.java:292)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:695)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:780)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:703)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.getDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:575)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.resolve(ResolveEngine.java:233)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.xsbt$boot$Update$$lockedApply(Checks.java:105)
    at xsbt.boot.Update$$anon$3.call(Update.scala:99)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:75)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:79)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.liftedTree1$1(Locks.scala:51)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:51)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:30)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:27)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.apply(Checks.java:100)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.update(Launch.scala:275)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.retrieve$1(Launch.scala:145)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$3.apply(Launch.scala:153)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:108)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anon$2.call(Launch.scala:138)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:75)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:79)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.liftedTree1$1(Locks.scala:51)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:51)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:30)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:27)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.locked(Launch.scala:174)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:91)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:89)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:51)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:69)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
    at xsbt.boot.Pre$.error(Pre.scala:22)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.xsbt$boot$Update$$lockedApply(Checks.java:105)
    at xsbt.boot.Update$$anon$3.call(Update.scala:99)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:75)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:79)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.liftedTree1$1(Locks.scala:51)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:51)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:30)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:27)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.apply(Checks.java:100)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.update(Launch.scala:275)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.retrieve$1(Launch.scala:145)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$3.apply(Launch.scala:153)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:108)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anon$2.call(Launch.scala:138)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:75)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:79)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.liftedTree1$1(Locks.scala:51)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:51)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:30)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:27)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.locked(Launch.scala:174)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:91)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:89)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:51)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:69)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
```

I've been really annoyed and been trying to fix it for at least 2 hours with no result.

Comment: Just a tip, I heard some opinions, that people had problems with apps based on the path with the space inside. So just to verify that try to create new app in for an example `C:\playapps\testapp` to check if it changes anything.

Comment: You could try clearing the Ivy cache, I had similar problems with a change of Play versions on Windows 7, the underlying version of sbt had changed too.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too familiar with Play, but it looks like your config is specifying the sbt version as `"${{sbt.version}}"`, which isn't being interpolated the way you expect.

Speculating further, I'm guessing that `sbt.version` is supposed to be a Java system property, but I don't see it in the list of variables that got set.

Re-check how you're specifying the sbt version, and how it is being used in your configuration.

Comment: I managed to hardcode a certain sbt version and  to get over half of the problem, but still got some errors